# Python curve for a lot points

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, points

I'm using Python and matplotlib.
I have a lot of Points, generated with arrays.
[image]

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=1, nrows=1, figsize=Groesse_cm/2.54)
ax.set_title(title)
ax.set_xlabel(xlabel) # Beschriftung X-Achse
ax.set_ylabel(ylabel) # Beschriftung Y-Achse
ax.plot(xWerte, yWerte, 'ro', label=kurveName)
ax.plot(xWerte, y2Werte, 'bo', label=kurveName2)
plt.show()
```

So I have the `arrayX` for x Values and the `arrayYmax` for Y Values (red) and `arrayYmin` for Y Values (blue). I can't give you my arrays, couse that is much too complicated.

My question is:
How can I get a spline/fit like in the upper picture? I do not know the function of my fited points, so I have just Points with [x / y] Values. So i don't wann connect the points i wanna have a fit. So yeah I say fit to this :D

Here is an example i don't wanna have:
The code for this is:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=1, nrows=1, figsize=Groesse_cm/2.54)
degree = 7
np.poly1d(np.polyfit(arrayX,arrayYmax,degree))
ax.plot(arrayX, arrayYmax, 'r')
np.poly1d(np.polyfit(arrayX,arrayYmin,degree))
ax.plot(arrayX, arrayYmin, 'b')
#Punkte
ax.plot(arrayX, arrayYmin, 'bo')
ax.plot(arrayX, arrayYmax, 'ro')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: "I can't give you my arrays, couse that is much too complicated.". You don't have to, you can give a _representative_ sample as part of a [mcve]

Comment: Maybe you can use something like a moving average? With enough data points it should lie close to your red curve. You can see this sometimes in statistical plots. Or you could create another function that is always taking the middle Y-value of two succeeding points.

Answer (score 0):

you're pretty close, you just need to use the polynomial model you're estimating/fitting.

start with pulling in packages and defining your data:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arr_x = [-0.8,  2.2,  5.2,  8.2, 11.2, 14.2, 17.2]
arr_y_min = [65, 165, 198, 183, 202, 175, 97]
arr_y_max = [618, 620, 545, 626, 557, 626, 555]
```

then we estimate the polynomial fit, as you were doing, but saving the result into a variable that we can use later:

```
poly_min = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(arr_x, arr_y_min, 2))
poly_max = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(arr_x, arr_y_max, 1))
```

next we plot the data:

```
plt.plot(arr_x, arr_y_min, 'bo:')
plt.plot(arr_x, arr_y_max, 'ro:')
```

next we use the polynomial fit from above to plot estimated value at a set of sampled points:

```
poly_x = np.linspace(-1, 18, 101)

plt.plot(poly_x, poly_min(poly_x), 'b')
plt.plot(poly_x, poly_max(poly_x), 'r')
```

giving us:

[image: polynomial fit]

note that I'm using much lower degree polynomials (1 and 2) than you (7).  a seven degree polynomial is certainly overfitting this small amount of data, and these look like a reasonable fits